# QT has undefined reference to 3rd party library

Tags: linux, qt, qmake

Currently I am learning to use a library called 'triceps'. I use qt-creator on linux platform and the compiler is clang.

The error message is

```
/home/developer/Projects/trytriceps/main.cpp:11: error: undefined reference to `Triceps::Unit::Unit(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)'
```

My .pro file is like this.

```
QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = trytriceps
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

LIBS += -stdlib=libc++
INCLUDEPATH += /home/developer/Projects/triceps-2.0.1/cpp
# This path contains libtriceps.a and libtriceps.so.
LIBS += -L/home/developer/Projects/triceps-2.0.1/cpp/build
LIBS += -ltriceps

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -stdlib=libc++
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

My main.cpp file is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utest/Utest.h>
#include <sched/Unit.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "hello world" << endl;

    Autoref<Unit> hwunit = new Unit("my unit");

    cout << hwunit->getName() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried to link to boost_regex library in this way and it works. Can any one help me? Thanks.

Comment: can you try a quick ldd libtriceps.so to see if some library link are missing ?

Comment: @BertrandMartel What's 'ldd libtriceps.so'? Thanks!

Comment: open a console, got to your libtriceps.so directory and type ldd libtriceps.so (ldd will print shared library for this lib)

Comment: @BertrandMartel I tried this command. It seems that all the dependencies exist.

Comment: I downloaded library and build it but make test failed with undefined references. Does your make test fail as well ?

Comment: @BertrandMartel Yes, make test failed but make all succeeded. Do you mean something is missing in this proj and I cannot get the workable lib?

Comment: yes something is amiss i think

Comment: @BertrandMartel OK, thanks for your help. I will ask the author of this library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a build issue (even if the `make test` still fail), I don't have the undefined error anymore. Your project file is working too.

If you have still the problem, here are the shared and static library I built :

`libtriceps.zip` (contains all cpp directory)
https://mega.co.nz/#!wENQUQoK!LIbeVH8gB94oS-zBrIlGHQ0iAICiRW6dOx620AInh0o

If you still have the issue make sure you have done a good clean, and regenerate a fresh Makefile with qmake

Comment: It turned out to a new error for .a and .so   :-1: error: skipping incompatible /home/developer/Projects/cpp/build/libtriceps.so when searching for -ltriceps

Comment: Actually I am developing under libc++ using clang++ as compiler. Do I need to change my compiler to gcc and not use libc++? Does it matter? Thanks!

Comment: I dont know my lib is a 32 bit architecture perhaps this is why it fail I will try to build on another 64 bit computer

Comment: I edited the build on 64bit. Your project work well on 64 bit though I didnt test with stdlib=libc++ nor with -std=c++11 flags

Comment: Thanks! I found that there's something wrong with my development environment. After I switch to a pure VM all things got to work. Thank you!